# PHP if $var null then return $var2

Tags: php, variables

I havent been able to find an answer to this:

My code works like this:

```
echo ' <p> '.$test2.'</p> ';
```

I want to make $test2 change if it is null i have tried the following code and bunch of other and it just breaks the page

```
$test2 = if(empty($price)){ return $pstatus};
```

Any help would be apprteciated

**UPDATE** I have modified my code, now it returns the price but if the price is empty its returning nothing when it should return the $pstatus

so $price is say 625000 is that variable is empty it should return sold from the $pstatus variable

```
$price = number_format($p->meta_box->REAL_HOMES_property_price);
$fimage = $p->better_featured_image->media_details->sizes->medium->source_url;
$ptitle = $p->title->rendered;
$pdesc = $p->excerpt->rendered;
$plink = $p->link;
$pstatus = $p->pure_taxonomies->{"property-status"}[0]->name;
$test2 = $pstatus ? $price : $test2;
```

Comment: There are lots of ways of doing this. Overwrite the variable, simple if-else `if(x) { echo $test1; } else { echo $test2; }`, temp variable `$tmp = (x) ? $test1 : $test2; echo $tmp;` etc etc Where x is the condition test.

Comment: `empty` is also useless when dealing with numeric values. `empty(0)` is TRUE, but you may actually want that zero.

Comment: *"I want to make $test2 change if it is null"* - You're going to have to elaborate on that. Where's this coming from anyway?

Comment: Enable all php errors by adding on top of your script : `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, then tell us what you see.

Comment: @Zeratops He already knows it's wrong. The error message won't tell him how to fix it.

Comment: @MarcB it's not `&&` but `??` [doc] (http://php.net/manual/fr/migration70.new-features.php)

Comment: And I notice you putted the comma after the ending bracket, which would probably throw an error. Put the comma inside your brackets like this : `$test2 = if(empty($price)){ return $pstatus;}`

Comment: @Gectou4: woops, right... d'oh. Too late to edit that, so I'll just nuke it.

Comment: I updated the post a little while ago... if i use the code here i just get a blank page ;)

Comment: so now you used a ternary from one of the answers but failed to mention that in the question's edit. Blank page, could mean syntax errors; check for them.

Comment: it's a pain this one, i'm hopeing i'm looking for null, it's getting it from an api it's pulling it from this `meta_box": { "REAL_HOMES_property_price": "",` i'm guessing "" would be null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it inline:

```
$test2 = $price ? $pstatus : $test2;
```

If you need to assign "$price" to "$test2" and if there is no price then assign "$pstatus":

```
$test2 = $price ? $price : $pstatus;
```

Comment: That should be the other way around `$test2 = $price ? $pstatus : $test2;` - Edit: Not my dv here.

Comment: @JonStirling it was probably the "general idea" as to why they got that +vote.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `is_null()`, if as you say you actually want to check for null

```
  $test2 = !is_null( $price ) ? $pstatus : $test2;
```

> want to make $test2 change if it is null i have

Be aware that when checking the value with `==` PHP will see `0, 0.0, false, null` and a few other things as false. If price is ever `0` it would be false, which may or may not be what you want or expect.

You can also check for `$price === null`  Three equals checks for type as well as value being the same.

Comment: it's a pain this one, i'm hopeing i'm looking for null, it's getting it from an api it's pulling it from this `meta_box": { "REAL_HOMES_property_price": "",` i'm guessing "" would be null?

Comment: That would be empty if its Json